# cassandra.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am new to cassandra and I am doing a Poc on it so, I have installed cassandra 3.11 on RHEL.7.5 VM. It was working fine for some days but when I restarted the service it failed with "pid issue".
I have verified the logs but not found any such error related information.

Can any one please help me in figuring out this.

Error Msg :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/up9Lx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, it is with /etc/passwd file.

earlier it was like this,
cassandra:x:994:49376::/var/lib/cassandra:/sbin/nologin

So before restarting the server i have changed the shell to bash. Now this is working for me.
cassandra:x:994:49376::/var/lib/cassandra:/bin/bash

commands to change the shell and restart are :

chsh -s /bin/bash cassandra

sudo service cassandra restart

Answer (score 0):

You can restart the cassandra services by below command. please go on cassandra installed then bin folder.
cassandra -f or ./cassandra -f